# Add background-color on the entire height div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a layout for an A4 size document and got this working as it should. However, whenever I use `height: 297mm` under the class `preview__bg`, it breaks in the actual live document. So I can't use the `height: 297mm`.

Is there any other way to solve this problem without using `height: 297mm`?

Version of what it should be: [JSFiddle: DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ga3mnz1c/)

Comment: probably a cascading of `height:100%` ?

Comment: without height what was the issue?

Comment: @TemaniAfif cascading? Could you check on Jsfiddle and try?

Comment: like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ga3mnz1c/8/

Comment: @BhargavChudasama: Without the height: 297mm, the background-color is not filled on the entire height of the div. Check the JSFiddle Demo added and change  `height: 297mm;` to `height: 100%` or `height: auto` from Line 49 in CSS. You will understand.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting. Let me test out the answer in the live version. Update: Tested no the live server and it broke the entire layout. Let me play around with it.